# Facebook Workplace Graph API - How do I get Group ID using Group Name

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-workplace

I'm using 'https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=group&q=&access_token=' to get Group ID. However I'm getting an error 'This resource is not available for Workplace applications'. I think I am trying incorrect REST Endpoint. Does anyone aware of an workplace endpoint that lets you get Group ID where Group Name is provided in REST request.

Thank you.

Comment: Using this rest endpoint 'https://graph.facebook.com/community/groups', I can get list of all groups but since group names are not unique I can cant apply filter on top of result coming from above rest endpoint.

Comment: Search endpoint is deprecated anyway, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#search-4-4